# Access VBA browseto pass parameters

Tags: ms-access, navigation, vba

I have a tabbed navigation. I have a bound form a user double clicks on a single user out of a long list. I want to go to an unbound form, and pre-load the form with details about that user (edit the user). I'm specifically using an unbound form because I want to show a save/cancel button. I can't find any way to pass the id of the user into the load_form call. Am I missing something? Must I use some sort of global (this seems bad to me)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenArgs when opening the form:-

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", acNormal,,,,,Args
```

And whatever Args is can be referenced in "MyForm" as Me.OpenArgs

e.g. if you pass a numeric PK then you could use something like:

```
dim db as dao.database
set db = currentdb
dim rs as dao.recordset
set rs = db.openrecordset ("select * from MyTable where PK=" & me.openargs", dbopendynaset, dbfailonerror)
if rs.eof then
'didn't find record with PK...
else
'then populate the unbound controls on your form with the fields from the recordset
...
```

Note that you don't need to have an unbound form just to offer a save/cancel. if you write an event handler for the form's Before Update event, you can cancel changes or commit them as you please.

Comment: You will not be able to navigate with an unbound form, yesno?

Comment: @Remou : you are quite correct, as always. I had mentally dismissed the need for an unbound form and ploughed ahead blindly. I shall amend the answer, and delete it when you have supplied your inevitable better one :)

Comment: Have a point for encouragement and as a promise to leave your otherwise good answer alone :)

Comment: Can't use openform with a navigation tab w/o losing your tabs, hence why I asked for browseto.

Comment: If you want to use tabbed navigation then it appears that you will have to bind your form and set the Where Condition argument of the BrowseTo action to specify the user that you require. If you are using Web Forms then you will have to use the underlying table's BeforeChange event to show a Save/Cancel message, otherwise a BeforeUpdate event on a regular form.